# Vim: Airline + Syntastic bug

Tags: python, vim, syntastic, vim-airline

I am unable to get Airline to work properly with syntastic. I have a clean installation of Python (3.5.3), Vim (where there are only Syntastic and Airline installed via Vundle) and Flake8.

When I open python code in Vim I get this message:

```
Error detected while processing function
<SNR>20_on_window_changed[13]..airline#update_statusline[18]..
<SNR>21_invoke_funcrefs[2]..airline#util#exec_funcrefs[2]..
airline#extensions#quickfix#apply[2]..<SNR>40_get_text:
line    3:
E716: Key not present in Dictionary: quickfix && !dict[0].loclist
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function    
<SNR>20_on_window_changed[13]..airline#update_statusline[18].
<SNR>21_invoke_funcrefs[2]..airline#util#exec_funcrefs[2]..
airline#extensions#quickfix#apply[2]..<SNR>40_get_text:
line    3:
E15: Invalid expression: len(dict) > 0 && dict[0].quickfix && 
!dict[0].loclist
```

What could this possibly mean?

Here's what my vimrc looks like:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

"=====================================================
" Vundle settings
"=====================================================
" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize

set rtp+=C:/Users/Ray/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'


" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype on
filetype plugin on
filetype plugin indent on


"let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
set laststatus=2
"let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
```

Comment: `E716: Key not present in Dictionary: quickfix && !dict[0].loclist`

Comment: `E15: Invalid expression: len(dict) > 0 && dict[0].quickfix && 
!dict[0].loclist`

Comment: What do I do to fix it?

Comment: That sounds like a bug in Airline, maybe you'll have more luck filing an issue here: https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/issues - in the meantime, you might want to provide your vimrc and how to reproduce, it sounds like a configuration issue on your end :)

Comment: This probably won't fix your problem, but according to `:h syntastic-airline` you should not mess with `statusline`, since `airline` is supposed to do it for you.